# Signal R Core 1.0.3 - Maintain Connection on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm currently building a Core 2.2 application using Signal R Core 1.0.3, and there seems to be no documentation on how to persist the connection or reestablish the connectionId when a user navigates away/back to the page.

Is there a way to re-establish the connection with a known connectionId once stored on the client side? I.E. Store the connectionId as a cookie, then restablish that connectionId if the user refreshes the page, or comes back later?

Comment: Why do you rely on the `connectionId`? That is mostly to recognize the actual *connection* (the technical thing) and as such is not a good way to recognize a user.

Comment: You should initiate a connection handshake where the user identifies themselves with an id, email etc. The connection id is just that, an identifier for a given connection. Once its dropped the identifier changes because its a new connection. It wouldn't make sense for the old connection to retain the same id as the new one otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SignalR dont provide a way to persist connection after page refresh. Every time user use the website they will have different connection id.

So we can store connection id in memory for user to work with signalr

I write small blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/send-message-to-specific-user-in-signalr/) to demonstrate the idea so you can take a look at.